# AVPlayer - iOS 13 - Long form video - No sound after unmuting device connected to an AppleTV

Tags: ios, avfoundation, avplayer, tvos, avaudiosession

I have a video player app with the iOS 13 AirPlay optimisation "Long form video" active (set in `Info.plist`).

Somewhere in that app, I need an (default muted) inline AVPlayer that the user can unmute.

However, when the device is connected to an Apple TV, the AVPlayer with `allowsExternalPlayback = false` and `isMuted = true`, does not have any audio after unmuting (`isMuted = false`) the player, not on the device nor on the tv.
Disconnecting AirPlay brings back the audio on the speaker.

Fun quirk: When the player is initially muted, the audio *is* playing on the TV.
When unmuted, no audio is playing anywhere.

The audio session is configured as follows (after unmuting):

```
try audioSession.setCategory(.playback,
                             mode: .moviePlayback,
                             options: [])
try audioSession.setActive(true, options: [])
```

My goal is to have the muted AVPlayer play the audio on the speaker when it's unmuted and ignore AirPlay all together.